# android 5.0 popup window clipping does not work

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, popupwindow

I have popup window which is a circle and I want it to be partially out of screen bounds. To invoke window I used: `popup.showAsDropDown(imageButton, OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y);` And it should looks like this:

[image]

To clip a view I used: `popup.setClippingEnabled(false);`
And it works, it looks as I expect on devices with API level below 21...

Unfortunately, on android L (lollipop) it looks like this:

[image]

Circle is clipped on top, but on right side it just come to the edge of screen. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

I attach source code in which I invoke popup window

```
private void showPopup(final Activity context, ImageButton imageButton ) {
    // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
    FrameLayout viewGroup = (FrameLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, viewGroup);

    layout.startAnimation(range_animation_start);

    layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    int popupHeight = layout.getMeasuredHeight();
    int popupWidth = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(layout);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
    popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
    popup.setFocusable(true);


    // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
    int OFFSET_X =getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.width_offset);
    int OFFSET_Y = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.height_offset);

   // Clear the default translucent background
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popup.setClippingEnabled(false);

    // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.

    popup.showAsDropDown(imageButton, OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y);
```